# Taking Tkinter Entry to fill in glob pathname

Tags: python, tkinter, glob

would like some help with this little issue.

I am trying to make a GUI interface where the user enters the folder name and the file name. Those values then get fed into glob function. I have set it up as below.

```
file_name = Entry(root)
folder_name = Entry(root)
```

I know that if I do the following, it will never work because they are in quotation marks.

```
files = glob.glob("folder_name.get()/file_name.get()")
```

So how do I get my entries into the glob function?

Comment: `glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_name.get(), file_name.get()))`, but you need to cater empty inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use f string in python.

```
files = glob.glob(f"{folder_name.get()}/{file_name.get()}")
```

Comment: This was going to be my answer. Good use of f-strings.

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign string variables to each entry, then use the .get() method to get the values of the variables and then feed it into the function.

```
file_name = StringVar()
file_name_entry = Entry(root,textvariable=file_name).pack()

folder_name = StringVar()
folder_name_entry = Entry(root,textvariable=folder_name).pack()

root.mainloop()

files = glob.glob(folder_name.get()+'/'+file_name.get())
```

Comment: Its not NECESSARY to assign tkinter variables, using `get()` on entry widgets will produce the same result.

Comment: you can use .get method on entry widgets it will return ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'```

Comment: It is because you chained `Entry(...)` and `pack()` together.